NgbAccordion not working after the upgrade of ng-bootstrap from v15 to v16
I am upgrading angular from v16 to v17, after the upgrade of core and cli. I tried to upgrade ng-bootstrap from v15 to v16 because it is compatible with  angular v17. But after upgrading the ng-bootstrap i am getting error while compiling that NgbAccordion is not supported in ng-bootstrap. how can i resolve this issue.The image show the error i am encountring
I tried use NgbAccordionItem insted of NgbAccordion but it didn't work.

Please share your code as snippet.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Try Changing the reference to NgbAccordionDirective instead of NgbAccordion, the file seems to be deleted and replaced with this NgbAccordionDirective instead
accordion.directive.ts
old api docs - accordion
new api docs - accordion

NgBootstrap 'deprecated' the ngbAccordian and related components in 14.1 and completely removed them in v16 (1 less than the Angular it matches up to) which is why your build breaks when you upgrade to Angular 17.
Unfortunately there are no migration docs so for me at least it was quicker to just rewrite it for pure bootstrap than work out from two different document sources what has changed and how to replicate the functionality we'd build on events and attributes that just don't exist any more.
